# How to use parentheses with one logical conective?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

is (((a and b) and c) and d) equal to a and b and c without parentheses?

Why?

Comment: Is there supposed to be an "*and d*" in the second option?

Comment: What happened to $d$? They are not equal, the left one is a well-formed formula and the other one is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, $\Big(\big((a\wedge b)\wedge c\big)\wedge d\Big) ~=~ a\wedge b\wedge c\wedge d$ , then this is indeed true due to the *associative property* of logical conjunction.

Comment: Okay that's what I thought. I sort of see it in my head now.